# Text On Image, how do i do this?

Tags: html, css

I have this:

[alt text http://azzyh.dk/newgen/area/member/b/videoklip.jpg](http://azzyh.dk/newgen/area/member/b/videoklip.jpg)

But i want to have place text in the middle like this:

[This is how i wanted. http://img251.imageshack.us/img251/4498/exvideo.jpg](http://img251.imageshack.us/img251/4498/exvideo.jpg)

How do i do it?

Im sorry forgot to mention i want this in the web.. so like html, so i would use a div or a span to do it

Comment: open paint and then type your text?

Comment: @Azzyh : Come on. At least state what programming language you want this done in.

Comment: @klausbyskov: That would take us about 1/3rd the way. What if this is the current state of his JPanel?

Comment: Azzyh, people here aren't mind readers, you need to give more info

Comment: Im sorry i want this in the web.. so like html, so i would use a <div or a span to do it

Comment: Seems like a valid question to me.  The specs are there: it must be done using HTML and CSS.  What's the problem, mods?

Comment: apphacker - how do I vote to reopen - I don't see it as an option?

Comment: I voted to reopen but we have a duplicate now :)

Comment: Language, what have you done, where are you doing, why are you doing it, details details details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you doing it on the web? if so, then you can use css/divs/spans to do it

google css layout tutorials and you'll be fine

Comment: Yeah I don't know why this question was closed. It's obviously a relevant question about how to place text over a background image. Yours was the best answer so I voted it up.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically, this largely depends on what dechnologies you're using. Are you reading in a bitmap, adding text, and outputting a bitmap?

What's the input, what's the output, and how do you want the program to operate? There are hundreds of answers to this question, and all depend on the specification.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with PHP, you could try GD:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php